# Braintree partail payment

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, braintree, partial-invoice

Is it possible to do a partial payment (with 2 invoices) in magento 2 with Braintree payment method ?

Answer (score 0):

Braintree module in Magento 2 allows performing multiple invoices per one authorization. The payment action should be `Authorize` in `Stores` -> `Configuration` -> `Sales` -> `Payment Methods` -> `Braintree` settings.

Also, Braintree SDK has a method for transaction partial [settlement](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Transaction.php#L584) but it is not implemented in Magento because this feature supports only PayPal transactions - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/submit-for-partial-settlement/php.